# Binding a radiobutton to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, binding, radio-button, razor-pages

I have a radio button on a razorpage, like this

```
<input asp-for="Order.CostCenter" type="radio" id="proj" name="CostCenter" value="proj">
<label>Project</label>
<input asp-for="Order.CostCenter" type="radio" id="dep" name="CostCenter" value="dep">
<label>Department</label>
```

the model for the form look like this

```
 [BindProperty] public OrdPurchase Order { get; set; }
```

and the model for the SQL look like this

```
 public string CostCenter { get; set; }
```

and the data type for CostCenter in SQL is varchar(80)

when I save the form the CostCenter is not binded to any value in SQL, it stays as NULL, but the rest of the forms values saves correctly

what can be the cause of that?

I want to save the value "proj" if "proj" is selected, and "dep" if "dep" is selected

[image]

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net core bind model data with name attribute.You only need to remove `name="CostCenter"`,here is a demo:
.cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Order.CostCenter" type="radio" id="proj"  value="proj">
    <label>Project</label>
    <input asp-for="Order.CostCenter" type="radio" id="dep" value="dep">
    <label>Department</label>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

.cshtml.cs:

```
 [BindProperty]
 public OrdPurchase Order { get; set; }
 public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return Page();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thanks, that worked!. what program do you use for making gif?

Comment: You can search on browser,and there will be many free programs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `asp-for` when manually assigning `id` and `name` of the input control.

```html
<input type="radio" id="proj" name="CostCenter" value="proj">
<label>Project</label>
<input type="radio" id="dep" name="CostCenter" value="dep">
<label>Department</label>
```

and use `BindProperty` for the object property with the radio button name:

```cs
[BindProperty]
public string CostCenter { get; set; }
```